# How to use AddForce and MovePosition together

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I amd trying to make my character jump and I am using an AddForce function to do it. The problem is that I am using MovePosition for the rest of the movement and the AddForce does not seem to work. Is there any wat to make these two function work together?
Thanks.

```
void Update()
{
    PlayerMovementInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, 
    Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

    MovePlayer();
}

private void MovePlayer()
{        
    Vector3 MoveVector = transform.TransformDirection(PlayerMovementInput) * speed;
    playerBody.MovePosition(transform.position + MoveVector);

    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        playerBody.AddForce(Vector3.up, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- If you want your movement to be physics based you use forces and velocity
- if you want your object to react/influence physics but the movement to be scripted you use MovePosition

As you see combining them makes not really sense.

You should rather do something like e.g.

```
void Update()
{
    PlayerMovementInput = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical")), 1f);
    MovePlayer();
}

private void MovePlayer()
{        
    var MoveVector = playerBody.rotation * PlayerMovementInput * speed;
    playerBody.velcoity = new Vector3(MoveVector.x, playerBody.velocity.y, MoveVector.z);

    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
         playerBody.AddForce(Vector3.up, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```